# Google Cloud SQL Proxy for Windows

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Does anyone know from where I can download a Windows version of the Cloud SQL Proxy?

I see on the support page an example command line, but there's no indication of where you could get a binary from. It's not on the Github.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is now a pre-compiled proxy version released, see the doc page for the download link: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sql-proxy .

Note that you must run the program in a command prompt; there's a feature request to allow a web-UI configuration rather than doing a command prompt.

If you want to compile to code yourself from source it is relatively straightforward:

1. [Install Go (use the .msi installer)](https://golang.org/dl/)
2. Execute the following in a command prompt (requires installation of git):

   > go get github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/cmd/cloud_sql_proxy
3. The proxy binary should be located in %GOPATH%\bin  (you should be able to do `cd %GOPATH%\bin` in a command prompt and then use `dir` to see the cloud_sql_proxy.exe file).

It's been a while since I've used windows for development, so let me know if there are any troubles.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I tried, but seemed to missing "golang.org/x/net/context","golang.org/x/oauth2/google","google.golang.org/cloud/compute/metadata"

Comment: What does running 'go get golang.org/x/net/context' (and the same command for the other three libraries) say? They work for me, but maybe they have issues on windows.

Comment: See edited post; there is now a precompiled version available.

Comment: Is there a way to use a windows service for the proxy?  I need the proxy connection on a windows server but I don't want to have to run this within the user environment.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to run the proxy as a windows service. I have never done it, though, and there aren't official docs about it unfortunately. If you are able to find a configuration which works to run the proxy as a windows service, please feel free to file a pull request to the github so that others can use it too!